# Not able to authenticate user by email_id in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

I want use email_id of the user as username but for some reason when i try to authenticate by email_id it is not working, it will be redirected to error page.

here is my implementation of security config

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select email_id,password,enabled from users where email_id = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select email_id,'USER_ROLE' from users where email_id = ?");
    }
```

PS: I tried surrounding `?` by `'?'` thinking email_id is not passed correctly.

**Login page JSP**

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/login}" name="f">
             <fieldset>
                <%-- <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">    
                     Invalid username and password.
                 </div>
                 <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success"> 
                     You have been logged out. 
                 </div> --%>
                 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                 <div class="margin-top-10  form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="margin-top-10 form-group">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                 </div>   
                 <div class="margin-top-10 form-actions form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <a class="register-link">Register</a>
                 </div>
                 </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: it doesnt throw any error it just gets redirect to /login?error page as configured on invalid credentials

Comment: Post your login page also make sure that you are actually have encrypted passwords in the database.

Comment: updated the question, and i do have encrypted passwords in DB, FYI : if i try to authenticate with contact_number it works fine, only with email_id it has problem

Comment: Is there is any way i can get the access to parameter passed from login page here? so i can debug and see what is happening

Comment: Just enable debug or trace logging for `org.springframework.security`.

Comment: Aren't Spring form authentication supposed to use `name="j_username"` and `name="j_password"` if custom names of these parameters weren't configured somewhere else?

Comment: @OleksiiDuzhyi: Not any more. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login.

Comment: It won't work with contact_number too without you adding any custom parameters as by default SS 3+ used 'j_username' & 'j_password' and SS 4+ uses username & password as credential attributes. You must have been passing contact_number as username but missed to add it while testing with email. Anyways, refer to my answer below, you'll need to override the configure method provided by WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: You can also debug if you wish to access the params passed from the login page. Just set a debug point in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#attemptAuthentication method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set something like this in your HttpSecurity form login configuration so that Spring security accepts your custom username and password fields:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().usernameParameter("email_id").passwordParameter("password").permitAll();
}
```